# How to change ip address on which sql server listens programatically

Tags: sql, sql-server

We need to change ip address on which our sql server instance listens programatically. 
We need to do this as we clone a new server from a template and then change its ip address, so we need to change ip on which sql listens.

Comment: Do you mean the port? The IP address is just the address of the server, and should change automatically for a new server.

Comment: can't sqlserver just listen to all hosts ip addresses?

Comment: we do not need to change the port. As server will have different n/w cards ie multiple ips. We need sql to listen on specific ip.